Yogakit.modulemap not found while generating Archive
I have upgraded react native project from 0.68.0 to 0.73.0
After that I have to add following lines in order to success fully tun the app in iOs.
And after adding it app running fine in the simulator.
post_install do |installer|
# https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
react_native_post_install(
installer,
config[:reactNativePath],
:mac_catalyst_enabled => false
)
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator]"] =  "arm64"
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.4'
config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
end
end
end*
But when I tried to generate the archive.
Xcode fails at the end and throw following error

